# How do I attach a click event to the hcmap function within Highcharter library within R shiny?

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

A snippet of the code I'm using to plot the map is given below, I've also tried using the 'hc_add_event_point' function, but to no avail

```
base <- hcmap(
      map = 'custom/world',
      download_map_data = TRUE,
      data = df_map_dat,
      value = "Population",
      name = "Population",
      joinBy = c("iso-a3", "iso_3"),
      allAreas = TRUE
    ) %>%
      hc_add_event_point(event='click')
```

I then try to retrieve click information using:

```
shiny::observeEvent(input$gmap1_click,{
                      print (input$map1_click)})
```

where map1 is the name of the output map plot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be created using the events.click available from the Highcharts API: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.events.click

Here you can find an article showing how to work with Highcharts JavaScript syntax in R: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR39-dztCuBUrncLQHEo9yNin00lRZfSqKY1JqAdvMU7KkokZGfTfj5DYB4